# What line of code should I add in order to receive only data between 2015-2021?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In the following code I want to find the number of mentions of people in certain newspapers. What line of code should I add in order to receive only data between 2015-2021?

```sql
SELECT
  person,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
 project.dataset.keyword
WHERE
  domain IN  ( 'israelhayom.co.il', 'ynet.co.il', 'walla.co.il', 'haaretz.co.il')
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

Comment: Is there a date  column in the table?  What is in it?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `WHERE   domain IN  ( ... ) AND date_column between "2015-01-01" and "2021-12-31" `

Comment: I tried this and I recieved an error: "Unrecognized name: date_column at [8:7]"

Comment: This is the code I tried:
SELECT
  person,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
 project.dataset.keyword
WHERE
  domain = 'israelhayom.co.il'
  AND date_column between "2015-01-01" and "2021-12-31"
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;

Comment: look at project.dataset.keyword table schema for a date column that you may use to see when the record was added; his date_column is an example

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  person,
  SUM(count_of_mentions) AS all_mentions
FROM
 project.dataset.keyword
WHERE
  domain IN  ( 'israelhayom.co.il', 'ynet.co.il', 'walla.co.il', 'haaretz.co.il')
 AND
<date_column> between "2015-01-01" and "2021-12-31" 
GROUP BY
  person
ORDER BY
  all_mentions DESC
LIMIT
  50;
```

Just replace `<date_column>` for the actual name of the column where the date is